# Go routines are deadlock when sending value to channel outside the go routines

Tags: go, concurrency

I tried changing a little bit on the code when learning Go select statement in  Golang tour: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5. However, i got issue:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.main()
        concurrency.go:26 +0xa3

goroutine 33 [chan receive]:
main.main.func1(0xc000088000)
        concurrency.go:24 +0x42
created by main.main
        concurrency.go:23 +0x89
exit status 2
```

Here is the code i tried and got the issue

```golang
func fibonacci(c, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for {
        select {
            case c <- x:  //sending value x into channel c
                x, y = y, x+y
            case <-quit:    //receive value from quit
                fmt.Println("quit")
        return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    //create two channels
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)
    go func() { //spin off the second function in order to let consume from c , so fibonaci can continue to work
        fmt.Println(<-c)    //read value from channel c
    }()
    //Try moving the statement that send value to channel quit in order to 
    //return function fibonacci
    quit <- 0   
    fibonacci(c, quit)
}
```

At first, i thought that the result will be same with result of  below code

```
//function fibonacci is same with the first one
func fibonacci(c, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for {
        select {
            case c <- x:  //sending value x into channel c
                x, y = y, x+y
            case <-quit:    //receive value from quit
                fmt.Println("quit")
        return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    //create two channels
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)
    go func() { //spin off the second function in order to let consume from c , so fibonaci can continue to work
        fmt.Println(<-c)    //read value from channel c
        quit <- 0 //CHANGE: move the statement inside the closure function 
    }()

    fibonacci(c, quit)
}
```

The output is

```
0
quit
```

Can you please explain what's the root cause of deadlock when executing the first example? 
And what are differences when  sending value to quit channel in the go routines with sending value to quit channel in the main thread.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `quit` channel is an unbuffered channel.  Communication on an unbuffered channel does not proceed until both a sending and receiving goroutine are ready. The statement `quit <- 0` blocks before the application executes the function to receive the value.  A receiving goroutine will never be ready

Fix by closing the channel:

```
c := make(chan int)
quit := make(chan int)
go func() {
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}()
close(quit)
fibonacci(c, quit)
```

... or by making the channel buffered

```
c := make(chan int, 1) // <- note size 1
quit := make(chan int)
go func() { 
    fmt.Println(<-c) 
}()
quit <- 0   
fibonacci(c, quit)
```

In this scenario, `fibonacci` will quit before yielding a value.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure that i understand you correctly,  the term "receiver are ready" in statement "communication on an unbuffered channel does not proceed until both the sender and receiver are ready." is understood as "receiver is created  and waiting". So i understood the root cause is I  sent value 0 to channel quit, so it blocks the creating of  the receiver fibonacci. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: The sender and receiver are goroutines.  A goroutine is ready when it executes the the channel operation.